# Can I protect my CRON scripts from remote users?

Tags: php, permissions, cron, file-permissions, user-permissions

I am currently working on a new project which involves using CRON jobs.

The CRON script basically runs an SQL query, generates the data into a file, and send that file to another server via FTP.

The script is on a live website (www.website.com/sendOrders.php)

I don't see any security issues or threats, and I think it is highly unlikely that anyone will find the PHP script on the server. However I don't want the script to be executed by any outsiders.

Is there a way I can protect this script?

Thanks
Peter

Comment: The easiest way would be to define a secret token, and to pass that from the cron job. The PHP file can be guessed or crawled, but the token can not.

Comment: Is there any posibilty that the token can be leaked, how would I pass the token through? POST or GET.  I have never used a CRON so I am not sure if they use POST/GET?

Comment: If it's an actual cron script, place it outside the webroot. If it's a webcron, put in a directory and let Apache handle HTTP authorization instead.

Comment: how do you call it?  via curl? or are you just doing something like php /path/to/sendOrders.php?  If you can't move it out to the web root, you can use apache acls to deny it being called Never mind the token.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could move your "secret files" into a subfolder, then create a [.htaccess file](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/htaccess.html) in there that prevents access to that file from everyone, except the server that is running the Cronjob.

Example:

```
DENY FROM ALL
ALLOW FROM 123.123.123.123
```

If you have shell access you might also put the scripts outside of the accessible folder and run directly via command line or cronjob like this: `php script.php`.

Answer (score 8):

Here is my solution:

In `cron.php` check if some specific header is sent

cron.php

```
if (secure_cron_script() === false) {
    echo 'Unauthorized';
    return;
}
echo 'OK';
```

functions.php

```
function secure_cron_script () {
    if (DEBUG)
        return true;

    $http_headers = getallheaders();
    if (empty($http_headers['X-My-Cron-token'])
    || $http_headers['X-My-Cron-token'] !== SECURE_CRON_TOKEN) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

How to call cron with curl:

```
curl --header "X-My-Cron-token: 321123321sd"  https://example.com/cron.php
```

No IP restriction. No GET/POST. If dev mode, skips restriction. You can put script wherever you want.

Comment: This is the best solution for me. Moving script outside is not possible if the script is writen inside a project using a framework like Laravel. Also, using htaccess restriction is not realy applicable. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Why not just move the script outside the Web-root of the server and execute it from CLI? This was there is no chance of anyone else executing it.

If you must have it in the webroot (and there should be no reason for it), just make sure that the client for the request is the server you are running it on, and it should be more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

This seems rather silly. Why have cron on `machine A` invoke a script via HTTP on `machine B`, when you could simply have machine B's native scheduling system (whatever OS it happens to be) do the job itself?

Then you could have the script tucked away somewhere that's not accessible via HTTP and render your security problem completley moot.

Comment: The script is running off of the same framework that the rest of the website is using.  If i move it elsewhere it won't work.. but I see where you are coming from.

Comment: Most decent frameworks will allow you to run parts of it outside web root.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are in a folder which shouldn't be locked down completely, wrap those lines in `<Files whatever.php>...</Files>`

```
<Files "cron.php">
  Order deny,allow
  Allow from name.of.this.machine
  Allow from another.authorized.name.net
  Allow from 127.0.0.1
  Deny from all
</Files>
```