# Carry out function only from localhost

Tags: codeigniter, cron

I want to set a cronjob over Plesk.
Now i have to insert the controller and function name.

If someone knows the link, he could carry out this cronjob everytime.

How can I ensure, that only the localhost carry out this function.

Comment: confirmed duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114466/can-i-protect-my-cron-scripts-from-remote-users

Comment: Just set [condition](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/common_functions.html#is_cli) in constructor of controller.

Answer (score 0):

Cron jobs are often run as PHP from a command line (especially if you set it to use php-cli rather than just PHP - your web host may be able to help with that one). However, it's worth noting that some web hosts set crons to run as just PHP.

In that case, you could set a condition to check that the script is being called from a command line. For example:

```
public function index()
{
    if(is_cli())
    {
       // Script has been called from a command line
    }
    else
    {
       show_404();
    }
}
```

In this case, if the call isn't from a command line, then they will simply see your 404 error page. `is_cli()` is a CodeIgniter function; more information on that in [the user guide](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/common_functions.html#is_cli)