# Improving security of PHP Cron Job for Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, cron

I am working on a **Wordpress website**, where I will have to execute some **cron jobs**. Most probably **the site will be deployed on a Linux shared hosting provider**, so my choices for running cron jobs are limited.

*My plan is to create a standalone raw PHP script that will be executed periodically using **Linux crontab command**. The script will internally call a URL on my Wordpress site, and perform some Wordpress hooks.*

> **My main concern is securing my cron job**.

Below I have outlined details of my plan, near the end of this post I have raised some security concerns. Please help me by suggesting a better approach.

---

### **1. Folder structure**

```
custom_cron
    automate.php    ===> This is my bot script
    flag.txt
public_html
    .htaccess
    wp_config.php
    wp_content/
    wp_includes/
```

---

### **2. Preparing the bot**

- The bot script will be located in automation.php, as per the folder structure shown above
- Using the Linux crontab command, automate.php will be scheduled for execution every day.
- It will be executed using PHP CLI

---

### **3. What the bot does**

- Check whether execution was already done today, by checking the flag.txt file
- If execution already done today, exit
- Get wordpress database username and password. (These will be hard coded in automate.php similar to how it is done in wpconfig.php)
- Connect to wordpress DB using PHP MySQLi
- Get a random token (generated by Wordpress previously) from wp_options table
- Using curl, call the URL http://my-wordpress-domain.com/nice-actions?token=step_6_token
- Update flag.txt, to denote that the bot was executed today

---

### **4. After the call to the Wordpress URL by bot**

- The URL called is a public facing URL. **But I do not want it to be accessed normally using a web browser.**
- Check for presence of token in query string and verify it

  - If token is absent / invalid

    - Exit giving 'Access denied' message
  - If token is present AND valid

    - Delete token from wp_options table
    - Execute some wordpress hooks
    - Regenerate token in wp_options table (for the next day)

---

### **5. Security measures I will take**

- Put the bot script outside of public_html to prevent aceess from the web
- No one can call the Wordpress site without knowing token
- When configuring crontab, run automate.php with least privileges (most probably I will use the owner of the public_html folder)

---

## Question: is there a better way for the following?

- Hard coding wordpress database credentials in automate.php and connecting using PHP MySQLi
- Using the wordpress database user exposes automate.php to the ENTIRE WORDPRESS DB
- When using a Linux shared hosting provider, is there any chance that automate.php can be called outside of crontab?

---

### Resources I have already looked at

- [PHP & cron: security issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387569/php-cron-security-issues)
- [Can I protect my CRON scripts from remote users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13114466/can-i-protect-my-cron-scripts-from-remote-users/13114495)
- https://blog.sanctum.geek.nz/cron-best-practices/

Comment: If the code at the public URL checks and sets the `flag.txt` file directly it doesn't matter what calls it since it won't do anything if the flag is not set. There doesn't seem to be a need for all this rigmarole with a separate script and a token: just get `cron` to make call to the public URL with `cURL`.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I cannot use only cron and curl to call the public URL, because without a random token in the query string web users can also execute this task

Comment: So? You want the task executed, and the flag file stops it executing more than once per day. Provided you ensure that any output is logged to the server and not sent to the web, it doesn't matter whether `cron` calls it, or some random user on the web.

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular Sorry my original post was not clear. I have edited it now. My Wordpress URL is public facing but I don't want anyone to access it via web. I only want to use it via cron. Due to project demand the URL must be public facing

Comment: You asked for a better way: I suggested one. Your scheme is needlessly complicated and provides no real benefit. If your code has to be web-facing then it will get called whether you like it or not. There's no functional difference between the code returning a 403 if it doesn't get a token, and returning a 403 if it's already run that day. Good luck.

Comment: The risk you're running putting the credentials inside `automate.php` is the same risk everyone runs with their `wp-config`, right? WP allows us to put `wp-config.php` one level above the installation folder. It works if it's outside the public folder. This is only an issue sometimes when some high-level plugin (backup, security) doesn't knows or accounts for this set-up. _(this is just a collateral observation not directly related to your question)_